# AngularJS SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I have a code that works but when I check my console I'm getting `SyntaxError: Unexpected token {` and here is the screenshot:

[image]

And when I check `line 58` of my `studentController.js` here it is `console.log(error);`. The complete code is:

```
angular
    .module('studentInfoApp')
    .factory('Student', Student)
    .controller('StudentsController', StudentsController)
    .config(config);

function config($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        controller: 'StudentsController',
        templateUrl: 'app/views/student-list.html'
    })
}

function Student($resource) {
    return $resource('/students/:id');
}

function StudentsController(Student, $scope, $http) {

    $scope.inputForm = {};
    $scope.students = null;

    function initStudents() {
        Student.query(function(data, headers) {
            $scope.students = data;
            $scope.studentsPanel = true;
            console.log(data);
        }, function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }

    initStudents();

    $scope.addStudentForm = function() {
        $scope.loading = true;
    }

    $scope.cancelAddStudent = function() {
        $scope.loading = false;
    }

    $scope.addStudent = function() {
        $scope.studentsPanel = false;
        var data = {
            fname: $scope.inputForm.fname,
            lname: $scope.inputForm.lname,
            age: $scope.inputForm.age,
            email: $scope.inputForm.email
        }

        Student.save(data)
        .$promise.then(function successCallback(response) {
            initStudents();
            console.log(response); //line 58
          }, function errorCallback(error) {
            console.log(error);
          });
    }
}
```

Am I missing something here? Thank you.

**UPDATE:**

Managed to fix it by correcting some variable.
In my php file:

```
$request = Slim\Slim::getInstance()->request();
$data = json_decode($request->getBody());
echo json_encode($data);
```

It should be

```
echo json_encode($request);
```

Comment: Do you need a semi colon after `var data = { ... }`?

Comment: @JackalopeZero With or without, still the same..

Comment: Can you make jsfiddle?

Comment: There seems to be some strange JSON coming in from your request. Can you check the network inspector in your developer tools and post the response of the HTTP request?

Comment: fixed it already guys. I updated my post.

Answer (score 5):

Your json response is not in valid `JSON` format. Fix that.

Comment: I strongly support this answer, this seems to be a problem with the received JSON-data, the JS is correct, even if a little strange. If you may post the raw data you recieve from the $ressource call, that would help.

Comment: You guys are right. I updated my post so you can see what I did with your help.